# Converting a Scala Iterator to a Vector

Tags: scala, vector

How do I convert a `scala.collection.Iterator` containing thousands of objects to a `scala.collection.immutable.Vector`?

I do not believe that I can use `_*` because of the number of items.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can

```
Vector() ++ myIterator
```

which gives the correct thing with the correct type.  For very small vectors and iterators, in high-performance loops, you may instead wish to

```
val b = Vector.newBuilder[WhateverType]
while (myIterator.hasNext) { b += myIterator.next }
b.result
```

which does the minimum work necessary (as far as I know) to create a vector.  `toIndexedSeq` does essentially this, but returns a more generic type (so you're not actually guaranteed a `Vector`, even if it does return a `Vector` now.)

Answer (score 6):

You can use `toIndexedSeq`. It doesn't statically return a `Vector`, but it actually is one.

Comment: Chances are OP does indeed just want some indexed sequence, and not necessarily a `Vector` specifically.

Comment: You are right. I need (near) constant-time random access and length calculations.

Answer (score 1):

You *can* use `_*`, since all it does is pass a `Seq` with all the arguments. It will be inefficient, however, since it will first convert the iterator into a sequence, and then use that sequence to create *another* sequence.

Answer (score 0):

Iterator supports .toVector now since at minimum Scala 11 (and maybe earlier).

```
class Thing
val myIterator = Iterator(new Thing, new Thing, new Thing)
myIterator.toVector
```

produces:

```
res1: scala.collection.immutable.Vector[Thing] = Vector(Thing@22da2fe6,
 Thing@100ad67e, Thing@713a35c5)
```